# Putting text/string function within an if function

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to put a text function inside another function (if statement) in excel:

```
=IF(C1 <> 0, ="INSERT INTO [dbo].[GPI_ASOC] ([GPI],[THER_CLASS_DESC],[GENERIC_NAME]) VALUES ('" & TEXT(A1,0) & "', '" & TEXT(C1,0)  & "',  '" & TEXT(D1,0) & "');", "FAIL")
```

If C row# <> 0 make the field say FAIL if not make the cell show the insert statement.

Edit: does not = 0 (<>)

Comment: In Excel, the syntax for "does not equal" is `<>` instead of `!=`

Comment: @tigeravatar ok thanks ill update

Comment: Remove the `=` before `"Insert...`

Comment: @ScottCraner Well, now I feel silly. I didn't realize it would evaluate without telling excel its a function.

Comment: You did tell Excel it was a function with the first `=`  all others are assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(C1 <> 0, "INSERT INTO [dbo].[GPI_ASOC] ([GPI],[THER_CLASS_DESC],[GENERIC_NAME]) VALUES ('" & TEXT(A1,0) & "', '" & TEXT(C1,0)  & "',  '" & TEXT(D1,0) & "');", "FAIL")
```